# How to add/subtract from elements in a list of integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer

I want to first convert strings of a list to integers and then add 1 to all elements, for example:

```
mylist = ["0", "1", "2"]
ints = [int(item) for item in mylist]
ints = ints+1
print(ints)
```

and then I want the output to be:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Not sure how I can do this, some help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to be able to do that sort of thing, you would be better off with a numpy array rather than a list.

Comment: `ints = [int(item)+1 for item in mylist] print(ints)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes that's the direct answer to the question as stated (or near enough - in relation to the existing `ints` rather than the original `mylist` it is `ints = [item+1 for item in ints]`) but it's not going to be a convenient or efficient approach if it is going to be needed extensively.

Comment: depend upon usecase. for small case it will be fine, other wise for large cases it won't be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
mylist = ["0", "1", "2"]
ints = [int(item)+1 for item in mylist]

print(ints)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy to solve this problem

```
import numpy as np
myList = ["0","1","2"]
myArray = np.array(myList, dtype=int) + 1
print(myArray)
```